Class Echo Control Tower Procedures
Northern Colorado Regional Airport (KFNL) resides within a surface echo. This airport, however, has an operating control tower. When VFR in echo airspace, ATC services are provided but not mandatory. So does that mean I don't technically need to speak with Loveland tower to get cleared to land? I guess it's just confusing that there's a towered airport that's not class D, C, or B. Thank you!

So-- why is it set up that way, a tower with a surface-level Class E circle around it?

14 CFR 91.127 "Operating on or in the vicinity of an airport in Class E airspace" address this scenario. Specifically, 91.127(c) requires two-way comms to be established "prior to 4 nautical miles from the airport, up to and including 2,500 feet AGL."
You do need to speak with NoCo Tower (not "Loveland Tower;" the airport diagram tells you their callsign) and you do need to receive clearance to land.
If you want to get even weirder, 91.126(d) similarly requires two-way comms with towers in Class G airspace.

Interesting.  So, are there any operating towers in Class G airspace?  Have there ever been?

...you've asked that before

NoCo Tower is a field test facility for remote tower operations. It's a contract operation, and only has partial staffing (right now, there's only one controller there), and is closed most of the time.
The "tower" consists of multiple high-resolution cameras that see the movement areas from multiple angles, and the controller is stationed in a temporary building (aptly named the "horse trailer").
The FAA probably saw no need to reclassify the surface area, since Serco (the contractor) was having difficulty staffing the operation from the outset.
Last I heard, Serco was pulling out of the project, which probably means FNL will need to explore other options. The airport certainly warrants having a tower.
